# Create query on laravel CONCAT and md5

Tags: mysql, laravel

How to convert my query to laravel? My $ID is md5

```
$ID = "aa8c96cf79a656e7ef095871ec061888";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE md5(CONCAT(`id`,`email`)) = '{$ID}' || md5(CONCAT(`code`,`email`)) = '{$ID}' ";
```

```
$order = DB::table('orders')->select(
??
);
```

Thanks

Comment: What is that good for?

Comment: Why are you generating IDs in this manner?

Comment: Seems like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
$order = DB::table('orders')->whereraw('md5(CONCAT(`id`,`email`)) = ? || md5(CONCAT(`code`,`email`)) = ?',[$ID,$ID] );
```

see here for more details:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#raw-expressions

Comment: of course, now that you know how it works really consider why you are using this pattern, it does not look like a good pattern to use and will cause a lot of head-aches in the future